# Android LogIn Page, HTTPPOST (possible AsyncTask help)

Tags: android, authentication, android-asynctask, http-post

Im trying to create a log in page to pull some information off of my school's website (schedule information...etc).  The code works perfectly as a java driver, but Im trying go get it to work on android.  I've been told by a friend that I should use an `AsyncTask` pattern. Could someone show me how to use an `AsyncTask` with the code below?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText un,pw;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);

        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    public void postLoginData() {
        //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("url");

        try {
            EditText un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
            String username=un.getText().toString();

            EditText pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
            String password=un.getText().toString();

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("userName", new StringBody("username"));
            entity.addPart("password", new StringBody("password"));
            entity.addPart("btnLogin", new StringBody("Login"));
            entity.addPart("__EVENTTARGET", new StringBody(""));

            //Post to login site
            httppost = new HttpPost("https://my.jcsu.edu/ICS");
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity response_entity = response.getEntity();
            if (response_entity != null) {
                Jsoup.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response_entity));
            }

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("url");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            response_entity = response.getEntity();


            if (response_entity != null) {
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response_entity));

                // Get the user's name
                Element userWelcome = doc.getElementById("userWelcome");
                System.out.println("Welcome " + userWelcome.getElementsByTag("strong").get(0).html());

                // Get the user's schedule
                System.out.println("\nCourse Schedule:");
                Elements gbody = doc.getElementsByClass("gbody");
                Element tr = gbody.get(4);
                Elements td = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
                for (Element e : td) {
                    if (e.html().contains("<ul>") || e.html().contains("<a"))
                        continue;
                    else

                        System.out.println(e.html());
                }

                // Get user's information
                System.out.println("\nAcademic Information:");
                System.out.println(doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_lblDivision").html()
                                   .replace("&nbsp;", ""));
                System.out.println("Faculty Advisors: "
                                   + doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_rptAdvisor_ctl00_lblAdvisorInfo").html() + ", "
                                   + doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_rptAdvisor_ctl02_lblAdvisorInfo").html());
                System.out.println("Intended Majors: "
                                   + doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_rptMajor_ctl00_lblMajorInfo").html());

            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == ok){
            postLoginData();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? There's no AsyncTask in the code above, but it recommended to use one on blocking operations, such as network activity. If not, you'll get ANR errors.

Comment: @323go well thats the thing, im not to familiar with the AsyncTask, I was hoping I could get a possible code snippit with it included

Comment: Gotcha, you might want to rephrase the question then -- I'll edit it for you. As it was, you're saying that AsyncTask was your *problem*, when, in fact, it would be your solution. Spacemanaki's answer below should point you in the right direction, as should the various tutorials you'll find if you google "Asynctask tutorial" -- especially vogella's. I will also comment on the answer below to as it contains a potential problem.

Comment: @323go What was the potential problem? I know the code doesn't compile, I figured the docs would make it clear how to fix it :P

Comment: @spacemanaki, as I had commented on your answer, the problem is that you're parsing the xml in the postExecute, so you're using the UI thread for what is potentially a long-running task. That'll give you an ANR.

Answer (score 1):

The method `OnClickListener.onClick` will be called from the UI thread, so you shouldn't do any long running operation from that method. From inside `onClick`, you call `postLoginData` which makes a network request. You shouldn't be doing that from the UI thread.

Unless I'm missing something, I actually don't see any reason to use an `AsyncTask` above, you could simply use a new `Thread` to do background work. This is because your method `postLoginData` just makes a request and prints some stuff out to `System.out`.

```
public void postLoginData() {
    new Thread() {
        // ... body of postLoginData()
    }.start();
}
```

However, I assume that you actually have some more code that isn't part of your snippet, or will add some later. If that code will update the UI after the network operation completes, you should consider using an `AsyncTask`. I will try to sketch out an example using that uses one.

You need to make any updates to the UI from the UI thread, but you can't do a long running operation, like a network request, on the UI thread. The basic idea behind Android's `AsyncTask` is to schedule work on both the UI thread and a background thread. This allows you to start downloading data, update a progress bar while the download happens, and update the UI when it finishes. Here's a basic sketch of how to implement `postLoginData` using an `AsyncTask`:

```
PostLoginDataTask extends AsyncTask {
    String username, password;

    onPreExecute() { // runs on the UI thread
        EditText un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
        username=un.getText().toString();

        EditText pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        password=un.getText().toString();
    }

    doInBackground() { // runs on a background thread
        //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("url");

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entity.addPart("userName", new StringBody("username"));
        entity.addPart("password", new StringBody("password"));
        entity.addPart("btnLogin", new StringBody("Login"));
        entity.addPart("__EVENTTARGET", new StringBody(""));

        //Post to login site
        httppost = new HttpPost("https://my.jcsu.edu/ICS");
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity response_entity = response.getEntity();
        if (response_entity != null) {
            Jsoup.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response_entity));
        }

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("url");
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        response_entity = response.getEntity();

        return response_entity;
    }

    onPostExecute() { // runs on the UI thread
        if (response_entity != null) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response_entity));

            // Get the user's name
            Element userWelcome = doc.getElementById("userWelcome");
            System.out.println("Welcome " + userWelcome.getElementsByTag("strong").get(0).html());

            // Get the user's schedule
            System.out.println("\nCourse Schedule:");
            Elements gbody = doc.getElementsByClass("gbody");
            Element tr = gbody.get(4);
            Elements td = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
            for (Element e : td) {
                if (e.html().contains("<ul>") || e.html().contains("<a"))
                    continue;
                else

                    System.out.println(e.html());
            }

            // Get user's information
            System.out.println("\nAcademic Information:");
            System.out.println(doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_lblDivision").html()
                               .replace("&nbsp;", ""));
            System.out.println("Faculty Advisors: "
                               + doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_rptAdvisor_ctl00_lblAdvisorInfo").html() + ", "
                               + doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_rptAdvisor_ctl02_lblAdvisorInfo").html());
            System.out.println("Intended Majors: "
                               + doc.getElementById("pg7_V_rptPackage_ctl00_rptMajor_ctl00_lblMajorInfo").html());

            // Any updates to the UI should go in this method
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is not entirely correct and will not compile. You'll need to [read up on the generic type parameters Params, Progress and Result,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and figure out how to fit that into your code. I've left it as an exercise for the reader :P It's not too difficult, but if you're confused feel free to ask in a comment...

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, I am doing some research on the asynctask and yet I am still thoroughly confused (at this point)